# Post Data Using AngularJS to MVC 4 Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

```
**AngularJs Post Request :**


   var url = 'http://localhost:54047/api/JobSaleBid';


            var student = {
                "firstname": 'dfdsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf',
                "lastname": 'k.waqas26@gmail.com'
            };

            data = $http.post(
                url,
                JSON.stringify(student),
                {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    }
                }
            ).success(function (data) {
                $scope.person = data;
            });


**Model:** 

public class student
    {
      public string firstname {get;set;}
      public string lastname {get;set;}
    }


**Controller:**

    public class JobSaleBidController : BaseApiController
    {

        public string Post([FromBody]student model)
        {
              return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
        }

    }

**Route Config**

  public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                     name: "DefaultApi",
                     routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                     defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
                 );
        }
    }
```

While  Posting  I am getting the following errors

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)

index.html:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:54047/api/JobSaleBid. Invalid HTTP status code 405

**Request Detail:**

Remote Address:127.0.0.1:54047
Request URL:http://localhost:54047/api/JobSaleBid
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:405 Method Not Allowed

The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.

Can any one tell me what is wrong, I have tried so many solutions but still not getting it worked, you help will be appreciated.

Comment: try to do it with fiddler to evaluate if is a configuration issue or is an angular issue. I'm almost sure that there is something going on your web config that is not allowing the post (is on the top of my head but I think you have to decorate your method with HttpPost

Comment: Here is the Web Config setting for accessing remote web api. <system.webServer>
    
      <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
        </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol><system.webServer>

Comment: Could you add the code for the "BaseApiController"?

Answer (score 0):

The jquery post should look like this

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: JSON.stringify(student),
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
});
```

and would strongly recommend you to use a Service/Factory to get data and inject them in your controller and then use them.

Edit:

Try adding `[HttpPost]` over your action.

Comment: still the same error,    [HttpPost]
        public string Post([FromBody]student model)
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
        }

Comment: Try removing `[FromBody]` and try once.

Comment: my    controller.js:               $scope.testpost = function() {

        $scope.student = {
            "firstname": 'dfdsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf',
            "lastname": 'k.waqas26@gmail.com'
        };
        
        var t = APIservice.testpost($scope.student);
      
        t.success(function (html) {
             alert(html);
         
        });
    };

Comment: service.js:               testpost: function (student) {

           
            var url = 'http://localhost:54047/api/JobSaleBid';
            
            alert(JSON.stringify(student));

            data = $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: url,
                data: JSON.stringify(student),
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
            });

            return data;
        },

Comment: Show me your `BaseApiController`

Comment: try using APIcontroller if possible instead of base API controller

Comment: public class JobSaleBidController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public string Post(student model)
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
        }

    }  but still the same error  :               Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:54047/api/JobSaleBid Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)
index.html:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:54047/api/JobSaleBid. Invalid HTTP status code 405

Comment: I am sending request to remote mvc web API from Hybrid Mobile App and also allowing CORS support to my server. both applications are running on same system with different ports. Mobile App URL: http://localhost:61123/www/index.html#/tab/camera and WEB API URL: http://localhost:54047/api/JobSaleBid

Comment: My Web Config:  through web.config:   
      <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
        </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this page: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/troubleshooting-http-405-errors-after-publishing-web-api-applications
I've encountered the same problem before. For me, adding the ExtensionlessUrlHandler fixed the problem.